# Can't delete user from group with ldapdeleteuserfromgroup

Tags: groups, openldap

I have user accounts with usernames that are numerical (I know [Ubuntu doesn't like that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287077/why-cant-linux-usernames-begin-with-numbers), sorry)

In this case, I have a username `18000011` who is a member of the group `students`:

```
~$ groups 18000011
18000011 : students teacher
```

I can't remove the user from the group the normal way:

```
~$ sudo ldapdeleteuserfromgroup 18000011 students
Group students not found (or 18000011 is not a member of group students)
```

So I tried to use the UID of `18085` instead of username:

```
~$ getent passwd | grep 18000011
18000011:x:18085:5000:FIRSTNM LASTNM:/home/18000011:/bin/bash
```

But same problem:

```
~$ sudo ldapdeleteuserfromgroup 18085 students
Group students not found (or 18085 is not a member of group students)
```

What am I doing wrong, and/or how can I remove this group?

**EDIT:**
Other [ldapscripts](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/ldapsetprimarygroup.1.html) are working on this user.  For example, I can set the user's primary group using GID:

```
~$ getent group | grep teacher
teacher:*:10004:90158,14000154,18000011
~$ sudo ldapsetprimarygroup 18000011 10004
Successfully set primary group for user 18000011 (to group 10004)
```

**EDIT 2:** Looking at `ldapdeleteuserfromgroup`:

```
~$ ldapdeleteuserfromgroup
Usage : /usr/sbin/ldapdeleteuserfromgroup <username | dn> <groupname | gid>
```

It doesn't accept user id, but instead dn, so I tried finding the user's dn:

```
~$ sudo lsldap | grep "18000011"
dn: uid=18000011,ou=Users,dc=hackerspace,dc=tbl
```

But I'm not sure how to enter the dn, tried the obvious, but no luck:

```
~$ sudo ldapdeleteuserfromgroup "uid=18000011,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com" students
Group students not found (or uid=18000011,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com is not a member of group students)
```

**Edit 3** I've also tried all of the above with gid of `5000` instead of group name, just in case:

```
~$ getent group | grep studentsstudents:*:5000:
```